# Subset adjacent values around one value

Tags: r

I have a vector of numbers:

```
v <- seq(1, 50, .5)
```

If I want to subset all the adjacent three values around one specific number: 25.

```
24 24.5 25
24.5 25 25.5
25 25.5 26
```

Are there any convenient methods?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the absolute difference:

```
v[abs(v-25) <= 1]
```

Comment: What a vagarious thought!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option to subset the values around the value 25 and then transform it to a `matrix` of 3 elements each

```
v1 <- v[which(v == 25)  +  (-2:2)]
embed(v1, 3)[, 3:1]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,] 24.0 24.5 25.0
#[2,] 24.5 25.0 25.5
#[3,] 25.0 25.5 26.0
```

Comment: You could do it all with sequences too I suppose, for `n <- 3` e.g.: `v[which(v==25) + (-n+1):0 + rep(seq_len(n)-1,each=n)]`

Comment: @tthelatemail Yes, that is possible